# Getting 'undefined' value from select options using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im trying to get selected value from whichever option I pick among the list. However, it mentioned as "Undefined"

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>Select Pizza Flavor </legend>
                    <select name="flavorlist" id="flavorlist" onclick="total()">
                        <option value= "">-Select Flavor-</option>
                        <option value="6">Cheezy Chicken (RM6)</option>
                        <option value="6">Spicy Chicken (RM6)</option>
                        <option value="5">Hawaii (RM5)</option>
                        <option value="6">Peperroni (RM6)</option>
                        <option value="5">Seafood (RM5)</option>
                        <option value="5">Beef (RM5)</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
```

javascript

```
function flavorprice()
{
    var flavorprice = 0
    
    var list = document.getElementsByName("flavorlist");

    flavorprice = list.value;
    
    return flavorprice;
}
```

I tried

```
function flavorprice()
{
    var flavorprice = 0
    
    var list = document.getElementsByName("flavorlist");

    flavorprice = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
    
    return flavorprice;
}
```

Still no value. How to fix this?
I'm learning jquery mobile.
I'm not used with $ yet since I'm really new to this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `getElementsByName()` returns a NodeList, not an Element. Therefore the `value` property is undefined.

To fix the immediate issue you can instead select the element by its `id`, as this should be unique in the DOM and will only return a single Element:

```js
function flavorprice() {
  return document.getElementById("flavorlist").value || 0;
}
```

However note that as you're using jQuery mobile, then you can use jQuery methods to achieve the same thing:

```js
function flavorprice() {
  return $('#flavorlist').val() || 0;
}

// ES6 version of the above:
let flavorprice = () => $('#flavorlist').val() || 0;
```